# how to calculate biquad coefficients for 3rd order low/high pass filters

Tags: algorithm, signal-processing

I found a lot of references on how to calculate biquad filter coefficients for first and second order low/high pass filters but none for higher orders.

I'd like to implement Nth order Butterworth filters for my speaker crossover program though. Can anybody please point me to the formulas I need?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23439615/2994596) for a 5th order example. Do you have specific difficulties with getting the Butterworth polynomial coefficients (which can be obtained with Matlab, python, linked applet, etc.) or factorizing the polynomial to obtain its complex roots?

Comment: I wrote a set of LADSPA plugins and a GUI to parametrize these. I need to recalculate them in the C code whenever the crossover frequency changes so matlab and python are out :/ And I need them in python for the GUI to show the frequency responses of the filters.
Any source of pseudo code would be welcome, I can adapt them to C and python myself.

Comment: Here's an example for the second order filter which i use: https://pastebin.com/1Wd1UPFS

Comment: FWIW I still am trying to figure out how to calculate the damn filter coefficients for 3rd order filters. I reverse engineered the code of butter() in scipy.signal, simplified it for the case of N=3 (3rd order) and tried to implement it in C. Here's the preliminary result: https://pastebin.com/sPVtgB1s
What I still need to figure out how to emulate numpy.poly() in this case, which takes the zeroes of a polynomial function and returns the coefficients of it. Any chance sombody knows about this stuff?

Answer (score 0):

here I go answering my own question:

I broke down the code of scipy.signal.butter() and implemented it in C for the case of N=3 (third order). The result can be found at https://gitlab.com/t-5/ladspa-t5-plugins/blob/master/src/coeffs.h (see the functions butter_3rd() and the two helpers poly() and convolve() ).